# As a hobbiest with trying to learn what exactly would a bench oscilloscope do for me?

Tags: oscilloscope

I'm overwhelmed by all the stats and options out there and I'm not exactly sure what I would even do with one as a day to day basis.

I have a little dso138 kit that I can see simple waveforms on currently and I'm still not quite sure how I would do something useful with this information.

What does a bench oscilloscope bring to the table for a beginning hobbies in this field?

*(I am not asking for a recommendation on any specific brand or unit, more in general usage)*

Comment: There's a [similar conversation](http://www.eevblog.com/forum/beginners/real-word-reasons-to-use-an-oscilloscope-as-a-real-tool/) going on at EEVBlog, and it's probably more on topic there than here.

Comment: It all depends on what YOU want to achieve and learn. Without an oscilloscope there are still lots of things you can do in the  hobby electronics field.

Comment: If you can't see how the DSO138 is useful then no words placed as an answer will satisfy you. Without knowledge of your experiences in the field of electronics there can be no advice that is meaningful to you.

Comment: If you don't know it, then it won't do anything for you.

Comment: @FakeMoustache -- kinda-sorta agree, but a) without a scope, you can never be more than a hobbyist and 2) hobbyist efforts are greatly enhanced by a scope.  A scope is an important tool for every electronics pursuit, and lack of a scope is a major handicap.

Comment: @Andyaka I've used arduino's to simple projects but that's about it. I wanted to learn more about the fundamentals and lower level ideas then whacking on a microcontroller and writing code. I only finished putting the dso138 kit together a few days ago so hopefully I'll figure out what I'm doing with it soon. So far I've hooked it to the capacitor in a simple astable 555 loop to watch see the 1/3 - 2/3 charge/discharge waveform.

Comment: @asawyer set up your Arduino to PWM, look at that on your 138. Set up two channels, then imagine how a two channel bench scope would allow you to compare them. Put the PWM through an RC filter, and look at the output, while varying the PWM parameters.

Comment: Absolutely everything you do with electronics can be done better with an oscilloscope.  Working without one is like reading in dim light -- sometimes you can read well enough to understand what you're reading, but other times you just plain need more light.

Comment: Scott's comparison is pretty accurate. You're effectively blind to most of the things going on in a circuit without a scope. It allows you to see the functioning of a circuit with considerably more precision.

Comment: I definitely agree a scope are your eyes in electronics. Without one it's very difficult to get stuff working. 2ch is a must, 4ch is nice for complex circuits. Bench scopes usually have more memory depth, faster sample rates, higher bandwidth, more options. Your entry scope may get along fine, but if you start building faster circuits it may not do the trick. A scope allows you to troubleshoot but also verify (!) your circuits operation. Does it work & react like I thought it would? If not, why? If yes, why do you think so? This thought process is important to be able to say it works fine.

Comment: An oscilloscope "maps" time and frequency into a 2D display that your eye-brain system can process. An oscilloscope is the heavy artillery of analog electronic testing and development. A meter may show an output as being at 3VDC. An oscilloscope may show a square wave that is 6% on and 40% off with a 0 to 5V swing. An oscilloscope will allow you to see that what should be a sinewave is really triangular, or how long after a 'trigger' signal a waveform commences, or .... much much much more.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One important benefit for you as a beginner is that you will be able to debug issues with grounding and insufficient decoupling of the voltage rails in your circuits. These are very common mistakes, and without an oscilloscope you can simply not find the problems - when you measure your voltage with a multimeter, it might look fine.

As far as I can see, your DSO138 only has one channel. Any real oscilloscope will have at least two channels, which means that you can compare two signals: how it looks like **before** you put it through a circuit you have built, and how it looks like **after** your circuit. This will give you a lot of insight into potential problems with your circuits, especially when you are trying to learn electronics.

Answer (score 3):

I use my oscilloscope a lot for communication debugging, so I²C, UART, SPI and others.

You can get away with a logic analyzer for that, but often it's not just the level but the signal integrity (especially with I²C), so you want to measure rise times, fall times, high levels, low levels, spurious flanks and other stuff.

Without a multichannel oscilloscope I'd be at a loss here. Especially when starting with new microcontrollers where I'm not sure if the peripheral will do what I think it does, it helps enormously.

For SPI you want to have 4 channels to get all the signals. You can use less (like only clock and mosi or miso) but it's great to have everything nicely time correlated to each other.

Analyzing dynamic current draw of components is also one thing I use it for regularly. Try to measure some current peaks which cause a voltage breakdown which causes havoc in your system with a multimeter - you might get lucky one time, but to get those reliably a scope is the way to go.

Or power up behaviour, how would you know if your supply voltage really reaches 2 V in 100 ms like it is required in the datasheet of some device?

---

Please don't read this post like: screw multimeters, get a decent scope. Once you have verified that your signal is stable with a scope, you can use your multimeter to measure the voltage with much higher resolution and accuracy than with a scope.

Scopes are often limited to 8-bit resolution (some offer 12-bit), and while they have a nice set of different ranges you won't get to the same level of resolution as a good multimeter.

Of course the need for resolution and accuracy depends on the work you do, but working with nice tools you can depend on makes a hobby that much more enjoyable, that I find it worth spending my money on them.